# How do i get my code to return the the answer without the extra '' and ()

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i get my code to return the the answer without the extra `''` and `()`?

```
def analyze_text(text):
    #removes all of the non-al charaters
    new_string = ""
    for eachLetter in text:
        if eachLetter.isalpha():
            new_string += eachLetter
    #count the number of e
    text_count_E = text.count("E")
    text_count_e = text.count("e")
    total_e = text_count_E + text_count_e
    #gets the percentage of e
    percentage = 100 * total_e / len(new_string)

    return "The text contains ",len(new_string),"alphabetic characters, of 
    which",total_e,"(",percentage,")","are 'e'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls, provide a more readable code listing the next time.

You can simply use format() method that each string object can perform.
This may be helpful.
https://pyformat.info/#simple

In your case it will be something like this:

```
return "The text contains {} alphabetic characters, of which {} ({}) are 'e'".format(len(new_string), total_e, percentage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You returned a tuple, not a single string

Try only returning the necessary values, then printing your output

```
return len(new_string), total_e
```

And outside the function,

```
new_len, total_e = analyze_text(text)
percent = 100 * total_e / new_len

print( "The text contains {} alphabetic characters, of which {} ({}) are 'e'".format(new_len, total_e, percent))
```